# Gitlab Runner on mac pro

Tags: macos, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've just finished installing gitlab runner on my m1 pro.
I have registered a runner 2 different ways with and without sudo.
Here's what I have:

```
me@MacBook-Pro pipelinetests % gitlab-runner list
Runtime platform                                    arch=arm64 os=darwin pid=49817 revision=bd40e3da version=14.9.1
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/Users/jlee/.gitlab-runner/config.toml
me-mac-docker                                       Executor=docker Token=asdfasdf-asdf URL=https://ourgitlabserver.org

me@MacBook-Pro pipelinetests % sudo gitlab-runner list
Runtime platform                                    arch=arm64 os=darwin pid=49821 revision=bd40e3da version=14.9.1
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
me-mac-docker2                                    Executor=docker+machine Token=asdfasdf URL=https://ourgitlabserver.org
```

In my gitlab project, I can see the runners appear under the "Available specific runners" list.  And i've made sure to add the right tag in my gitlab-ci.yml file.  But when I run the pipeline, it's stuck with the error:

```
This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online or available with any of these tags assigned to them: me-mac-docker23

Go to project CI settings
```

here's the list of runners:

[image]

And lastly here my code:

```yaml
stages:
  - unit-test

Test:
  stage: unit-test
  environment:
    name: development
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  script:
    - curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
    - apt-get install curl && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
    - apt-get install nodejs
    - npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
    - cd ./tests
    - dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=..\TestResults      est-results.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./TestResults/test-results.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - ./TestResults/test-results.xml
  except:
    - master
  tags:
    - me-mac-docker23
```

One thing that's not clear to me is when i create the runners, what value should I specify for the executor?

I chose the default which was ruby:2.7
I've tried to find some article that explains what the list of values can be but so far no dice.

Please and thanks.

EDIT 1

Heres a screenshot showing you the status of the runner and when it was last contacted: (just showing one, but both say they're running)

[image]

Comment: Did you assign the runner to the project? Also do you see the "last contact time" value in the UI? While your runners are registered, your runners may not be _running_. Double check the runner process is running without errors.

Comment: @sytech yeah both runners are dedicated to the project.  I added a screenshot showing an overview of one of them - please see Edit 1.

Comment: @sytech - should the name in the "tags" section of the gitlab-ci.yml file match the tags associated with the runner or the actual runner name?

Comment: If it says "Never" for "Last contact time" then your runner is registered, but is not running and contacting GitLab to pickup jobs. You may have a misconfiguration or your runner process is simply not running. You may have to run `gitlab-runner run` on the host where your runner is located. "Active" does not mean anything significant in this context (like whether the runner is actually alive or not) except that the runner is allowed to receive jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your runner is registered and your tag settings are correct. However, it appears that your runner is not running based on the "Last Contact Time" being stated as "Never".

Runner registration and *running* your runner are two separate steps. Just because your runner is registered doesn't mean it will pick up jobs. You need to run `gitlab-runner run` as the user you want to use for the executor on the runner host.

Verify that your runner is running (you should see a `gitlab-runner` process) and that there are no obvious errors in its logs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently and it was because `gitlab-runner` is trying to log to a location that it does not have permission to.  There's no error message so it just sits silently.
The solution was to set the logging locations inside the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist`

I just ran

```
touch ~/.gitlab-runner/out.log
touch ~/.gitlab-runner/err.log
```

And then set the logging locations in the plist to those files.

A more thorough explanation can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28389)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using docker as executor we can use shell, and run `.gitlab-runner --debug run` to see what is going on in the terminal